# PyQt5 store time of keyPressEvent

Tags: python, pyqt5

**Issue:**

I have a program where I will be showing several pages with a stacked widget, and users will have to press a button (using code I've written below) to go to the next page of the stacked widget. What I am trying to do is to calculate the time the reaction time of the user. So to measure how quick they were to press a button.

**Possible solution:**

I was thinking of storing the time that a key was pressed (point B) and the time that the page was shown (point A) and to subtract these points to get the reaction time. I was thinking of using a QTimer running throughout all the pages and whenever a key is pressed, it will store the time in a variable (that would be point b). And store the time that the page was shown (point a), and subtract these points to get the reaction time. *However, I am quite a beginner in coding and don't know how I would code this. Or whether there is a simpler way.*

The second solution I thought of was to used QElapsedTimer, *but I don't know how to code that either.*

**Button press:**

I have also created a subclass of a QWidget that will emit a signal every time I press the key 'F' or 'J' (KeybaordWidget). So I was thinking, I would need to write a function that does what I have described and connect that function to the 'fPress' or 'jPress' signal.

```
class KeyboardWidget (QWidget):
    fPress = pyqtSignal(str)
    jPress = pyqtSignal(str)
    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_F:
            self.fPress.emit('f')
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_J:
            self.jPress.emit ('j')
```

Comment: Is there a question? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `keyPressEvent` method, you can get the actual time in milliseconds since the epoch with `time.time()`, and save that in an attribute of your `KeyboardWidget` class. On the next `keyPressEvent` call, you can get the time again, subtract the first time from the second time, and you have the time in milliseconds the user needed between two button presses.

```py
import time

class KeyboardWidget(QWidget):
    ...
    
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.last_time = time.time()

    def keyPressEvent(self,event): 
        actual_time = time.time()
        print(actual_time - self.last_time) # will print the duration since the button was pressed the last time in milliseconds
        self.last_time = actual_time

        if event.key() == Qt.Key_F:
            self.fPress.emit('f')
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_J:
            self.jPress.emit ('j')
```

Comment: could you give me an example in code? I am quite new to python!

Comment: @jessie i added an example to my answer